# Applying Bayes' rule to simple probability

Tags: math, probability

I am reading up on some probability, and am looking to see how I would apply Bayes' rule

> P(A|B) = (P(B|A)*P(A)) / P(B)

to a certain situation. The question states:

> We have an authentication system. The system has a false positive rate
>   of 3% and a false negative rate of 2%. Assume we know that 1% of all
>   authentication attempts are by hackers.
>
> What is the probability that, when an authentication request is
>   rejected, it is due to a hacker (true negative) and not a rejected
>   real user (false negative)?

Just a little confused how I would use this info to plug into Bayes' rule.

P(B) in this case, I assume, is that the authentication request was rejected.

P(A) would be that the reject was because of a hacker (true negative).

So far, I feel:

P(A) = 1%

P(B|A) = 98% (100% - 2%)

P(B) = ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

P(B) = the probability of being rejected (whether hacker or not) = 0.99*0.03 + 0.01*(1-0.02)

P(B|A) = the probability of being rejected, given that you are a hacker = 1-0.02

P(A) = the probability that the one attempting is a hacker = 0.01

from here you can use the bayes rule.